# MySQL installed with homebrew stopped working

Tags: mysql, laravel, locking, homebrew, laravel-valet

I'm running Laravel with Valet on localhost. The other day my DB stopped working and I got this error.

I've tried varies solutions from StackOverlfow but nothing seems to work for good.
I had some success with re-installing MySQL. First it worked, then after a restart the error returned as if nothing had happened.

Any ideas and possible solutions are welcome!

````
2019-11-22T07:28:20.732087Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2019-11-22T07:28:20.833268Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:28:21.834984Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:28:22.838856Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:28:23.844548Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:28:24.848946Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:28:25.849871Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:28:26.854401Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:28:27.859471Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:28:28.862669Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:28:29.867559Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:28:30.868884Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:28:31.873861Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:28:32.878402Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:28:33.882308Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:28:34.885179Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:28:35.887673Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:28:36.890348Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:28:37.894877Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:28:38.900421Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:28:39.904220Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:28:40.909429Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:28:41.913230Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:28:42.918485Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:28:43.923973Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:28:44.927397Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:28:45.931041Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:28:46.935998Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:28:47.941222Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:28:48.943928Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:28:49.945988Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:28:50.950217Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:28:51.955518Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:28:52.960605Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:28:53.965354Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:28:54.970208Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:28:55.976164Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:28:56.982518Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:28:57.984856Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:28:58.987334Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:28:59.990658Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:00.995798Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:01.997097Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:02.999242Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:04.005513Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:05.010475Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:06.014483Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:07.020468Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:08.026727Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:09.029067Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:10.033853Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:11.036066Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:12.041863Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:13.045891Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:14.050010Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:15.055826Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:16.062497Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:17.068520Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:18.074686Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:19.081226Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:20.084656Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:21.086282Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:22.089582Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:23.095008Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:24.098510Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:25.101950Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:26.108228Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:27.116696Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:28.123539Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:29.129444Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:30.135448Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:31.140923Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:32.144339Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:33.150813Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:34.156732Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:35.160435Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:36.165699Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:37.172622Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:38.180502Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:39.184494Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:40.188930Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:41.192453Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:42.196437Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:43.198767Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:44.206068Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:45.212700Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:46.216042Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:47.222179Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:48.227701Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:49.234171Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:50.236459Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:51.241873Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:52.245806Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:53.249358Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:54.254697Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:55.262889Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:56.269719Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:57.276984Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:58.283896Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:29:59.287215Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:30:00.291169Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:30:01.297730Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
2019-11-22T07:30:01.301008Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012592] [InnoDB] Operating system error number 35 in a file operation.
2019-11-22T07:30:01.302042Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012596] [InnoDB] Error number 35 means ‘Resource temporarily unavailable’
2019-11-22T07:30:01.304279Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012215] [InnoDB] Cannot open datafile ‘./ibdata1’
2019-11-22T07:30:01.305396Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012959] [InnoDB] Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not remove old data files which contain your precious data!
2019-11-22T07:30:01.306751Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Cannot open a file.
2019-11-22T07:30:01.308318Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2019-11-22T07:30:01.309340Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2019-11-22T07:30:01.310976Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-11-22T07:30:01.311578Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.18_1/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.18)  Homebrew.```
````

Answer (score 3):

You might want to copy/delete ibdata1 from `/usr/local/var/mysq`

then restart MySQL `brew services start mysql`

Answer (score 0):

i didn't work with homebrew before ,but try to change the port you are using .

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have more than one MySQL installed. One is up and running and the other is attempting to start but cannot. Perhaps you have both MySQL and MariaDB running? That could do it.

It's also possible the same installation is attempting to run MySQL twice (depending on the configuration on what programs boot up when the computer starts).

Comment: I think you're right. I've tried all the answers, and uninstalled both brew and mysql, and looked for other DB software on the computer, but with little luck.

I ended up formatting the copmuter, and start from scratch :)

Answer (score 0):

Though it is quite old thread, still helps somebody. You have another installation which is already running from daemon.

Find from where MySQL is getting Auto started

## `sudo launchctl list | grep -i mysql`

Say Result :
10133   1   com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld

Then remove it.  Below command parameter changes as per output of your previous command.

## `sudo launchctl remove com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld`